# How does the Hibernate Generator model forking foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, code-generation, reverse-engineering

Our PostgreSQL database has 200+ tables and we wanted to give a try to the "Reverse Engineering" of Hibernate, in order to **avoid writing all VOs and/or Entity classes by hand**.

However, we have a few quirky foreign keys in our database that, and I wanted to understand how Hibernate models before jumping into the unknown. Here's an example that shows a "forking foreign key" (exaggerated for impact) that I think serves well to depict the case we are facing:

```
create table person (
  id int primary key not null,
  sid int not null unique,
  name varchar(30)
);

insert into person (id, sid, name) values
  (1, 3, 'Victor'),
  (2, 4, 'Juliett'),
  (3, 5, 'Oscar'),
  (4, 1, 'Romeo'),
  (5, 2, 'Mike');

create table applicant (
  id int primary key not null,
  sid int not null unique,
  referrer_id int not null, -- THIS IS THE FORKING FOREIGN KEY!
  foreign key (referrer_id) references applicant (id), -- fk #1
  foreign key (referrer_id) references applicant (sid), -- fk #2
  foreign key (referrer_id) references person (id), -- fk #3
  foreign key (referrer_id) references person (sid), -- fk #4
  friend_id int not null,
  foreign key (friend_id) references applicant (id) -- fk #5
);

insert into applicant (id, sid, referrer_id, friend_id) values
  (1, 2, 3, 5),
  (2, 5, 1, 3),  
  (3, 4, 5, 2),
  (4, 1, 1, 4),
  (5, 3, 2, 3);
```

Since the `referrer_id` in table `applicant` *points* to four different places... how does Hibernate models this forking FK, while reverse engineering it?

Will it produce four separate properties, once for each parent? Or maybe four separate methods, one for each parent?

Answer (score 1):

For reverse engineering from a relational database like PostgreSQL you could try Telosys ( http://www.telosys.org/ ). Telosys is a lightweight code generator working with 2 kinds of models, and particularly (in your case) a “Database model” that can be created and updated from a database schema (the reverse engineering process is based on JDBC metadata). See http://www.telosys.org/models.html

Once the model is created (or updated) you can use templates to generate you code (it’s very efficient for boilerplate code like entities, DAO, etc). The templates are fully customizable, so you can adapt existing templates or create your own template in order to generate exactly what you want ( cf http://www.telosys.org/templates.html )

For more information you can take a look at this post : https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/

Answer (score 0):

After searching around we came to the conclusion that Hibernate's Reverse Engineering is far from an automated process. Please correct me if I'm wrong. It cannot be automated and is, therefore, **a semi-automated process that requires a lot of user interaction, every time**. This is due to Hibernate's configuration being quite incomplete, something that prevents its automation.

If this is the case, then Hibernate is of no use to us since the database keeps evolving and we'll need to *refresh* our Java code often, something that can lead to [a lot of] human error.

I would love to be contradicted. That would allow us to actually use Hibernate. Please do.